# Typescript HTTP Get response type as text

Tags: angular, http, get, request

I am having a HTTP Get request written in Typescript

Code snippet:

```
    getMessageContent(messageContentId?: string): Observable<string> {
    const url = this.commonService.getApi('my-service/message-content/' + messageContentId);
    return this.httpClient.get<string>(url, {});
}
```

And I want to make response type as text, something like :

```
return this.httpClient.get<string>(url, {responseType: 'text'});
```

But I am getting error which says:

> The type "Observable" cannot be assigned to the type "Observable".
> The type "ArrayBuffer" cannot be assigned to the type "string".

How do I fix that?

Comment: Does `getApi` return `string`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get the url from the first api call and then use the value on the second api call, so you can use `switchMap` for that!

```
getMessageContent(messageContentId?: string): Observable<string> {
     return this.commonService.getApi('my-service/message-content/' + messageContentId).pipe(
         switchMap(url => this.httpClient.get<string>(url, {})
     );
}
```